# Using "is not NULL" command on SQL Server is giving me "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's the code I'm using:

```
SELECT [Año],
       [Producto],
       ROUND(SUM(Tareas),0) as 'Tareas'
FROM [rstudio].[dbo].[siembra_rd]
WHERE [Año] not in(2021), Tareas is not null
GROUP BY [Año], [Producto]
```

Comment: Whats the rest of the error? And please put the error in the question and actually ask a question. You are missing and `AND` (or `OR`) between your 2 `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the comma, not the boolean expressions.  Presumably, you intend one of the following:

```
WHERE [Año] not in (2021) AND Tareas is not null
```

or:

```
WHERE [Año] not in (2021) OR Tareas is not null
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: THanks. I haven't used SQL in ages (literally) and absolutely forgot that expressions under WHERE shouldn't be separated with comma.